# beautifulsoup4 - how can I print text and href at the same time?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have read more than 10 posts about print href, text but I could not find one that prints text and href same time.

The site is https://cyware.com/cyber-security-news-articles

I want crawling text of the post and url

This is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = urlopen("https://cyware.com/cyber-security-news-articles")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')

questions = soup.find_all('h2',{"class":"post post-v2 format-image news-card get-id"})

for h2 in soup.find_all('h2'):
    print(h2.text)
    print(h2.href)
```

But result of href is none.
I want know why `print(h2.href)`  doesn't print link.

questions contains href="~~"

```
<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" class="action_url" href="https://in.reuters.com/article/us-iran-cyber-hackers/iran-hit-by-global-cyber-attack-that-left-u-s-flag-on-screens-idINKBN1HE0MH">Iran hit by global cyber attack that left U.S. flag on screens with a warning “Don’t mess with our elections”</a>
```

[the html source that i want parsing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkCgE.jpg)

[result of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhzCJ.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to print both at the same time - titles and related href of articles you can do it in one run through the html. When getting the href you need to search for the 'a' tag.

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) 
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0'}
req = requests.get('https://cyware.com/cyber-security-news-articles', 
headers=headers)

html = bs.BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")

for i in html.find_all('h2',attrs={'class':"post-title post-v2-title text- 
image"}):
    print(i.text)
    for url in i.find_all('a'):
        print(url.get('href'))
```

Comment: i solve this problem based by your idea, just use 3 lines <br> for a in soup.find_all("a",{'rel':True},"action_url") :
 print(a.text)
 print(a.get('href'))

Comment: No problem. If this helped you solve your problem please don't forget to accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's better to use [`CSS selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). Notice that, if you target all the `h2` with the exact `post-title post-v2-title text-image` class, your code is vulnerable to changes on the website. If the maintainers will reorder or remove one of these classes from the `h2` title, your code will no longer work. Here is the leaner and in my opinion more readable version of the code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get('https://cyware.com/cyber-security-news-articles')

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')

for a in soup.select('.post h2[class*="title"] a'):
    print(a.text, a['href'])
```

`'.post h2[class*="title"] a'` selects all the `a` that are children of `h2` with a class containing `title` that are children of the element with `post` class.

Answer (score 0):

`find_all('h2')` is finding all `<h2></h2>` header elements, which is not an `<a href`. To find the `href` and its text, use `find_all('a')`:

```
result = [[i.text, i['href']] for i in soup.find_all('a', {'class':'action_url'})]
```